# Finding $\sin\left(\cot^{-1}\frac{x}{2}\right)$, trouble understanding the solution

Tags: trigonometry

Finding $\sin\left(\cot^{-1}\frac{x}{2}\right)$

---

[image]

I do not understand why they are considering only positive values. What has it to do with the range of $\cot^{-1}$ ? Could somebody dumb it down for me please Thanks!

Comment: There's no logical necessity that $x$ be positive and it's slightly disingenuous of the solution to suggest that the range of $\cot^{-1}$ requires it.

So in short they are making a simplifying assumption: suppose $x$ is positive. Then $\sin(\cot^{-1}(x/2)) = ...$. As an exercise for yourself, figure out what the expression would be if $x$ were negative.

Comment: if $x$ is negative, do i get $\sin\left(\cot^{-1}\frac{x}{2}\right)=\dfrac{-2}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}$ ?  because the angle will be in IVth quadrant where sine value is negative. I'm bit confused as it seems wolfram is also assuming x is positive

Comment: Yes. The fact that you have deduced the correct expression is another good reason why we should not think of Wolfram as having the last word! Our squishy brains are still much, much better.

Comment: your reply clears up some of the confusion actually, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The range for the inverse cotangent is commonly taken to be $(0,\pi)$, where the sine is positive.

In general, we have
$$
\sin^2t=\frac{\sin^2t}{\sin^2t+\cos^2t}=\frac{1}{1+\cot^2t}
$$
dividing numerator and denominator by $\sin^2t$.

If $t=\cot^{-1}(x/2)$, you can then use
$$
\sin t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\cot^2t}}
$$
Therefore
$$
\sin\cot^{-1}(x/2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\cot^2t}}=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(x/2)^2}}
$$

---

If the range of the inverse cotangent is taken to be $(-\pi/2,0)\cup(0,\pi/2]$ the statement is surely wrong, because
$$
\frac{2}{\sqrt{4+x^2}}>0
$$
but $\sin\cot^{-1}(x/2)$ would be negative for $x<0$.

I've never seen that set being considered as the range of the inverse cotangent. The correct result in that case would be
$$
\sin\cot^{-1}\frac{x}{2}=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{4+x^2}} & \text{if $x\ge0$}\\[6px]
-\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{4+x^2}} & \text{if $x<0$}
\end{cases}
$$

But I can't think of a good reason for the inverse cotangent being 
defined that way, making it a non continuous function at $0$.